# Gems Install Bundle Fails

Tags: ruby, docker, ubuntu, rubygems

Docker ubuntu on MacOS gets the following error:

```
gem install bundler
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Root CA/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com to your local trusted store
```

```
curl -Lks 'https://git.io/rg-ssl' | ruby
Here's your Ruby and OpenSSL environment:

Ruby:           2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091eafcce70ffb75ddf7e121e192ab217) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
RubyGems:       3.1.2
Bundler:        2.1.2
Compiled with:  OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
Loaded version: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
SSL_CERT_FILE:  /usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem
SSL_CERT_DIR:   /usr/lib/ssl/certs

With that out of the way, let's see if you can connect to rubygems.org...

Bundler connection to rubygems.org:       failed  ❌  (certificate verification)
ERROR:  SSL verification error at depth 2: unable to get local issuer certificate (20)
ERROR:  You must add /C=US/ST=California/L=San Jose/O=Zscaler Inc./OU=Zscaler Inc./CN=Zscaler Root CA/emailAddress=support@zscaler.com to your local trusted store
RubyGems connection to rubygems.org:      failed  ❌  (certificate verification)
Ruby net/http connection to rubygems.org: failed  ❌
```

Any help on how can I get past this?

Comment: That sounds like someone in your network might have inserted a proxy that intercepts and rewrites network traffic.  Searching SO for "zscaler" finds some similar questions and suggests some workarounds, but you might prefer a path where you have a working trusted TLS-secured path to the RubyGems service.

Comment: You should probably check with your local IT helpdesk on how they (i.e. the admins of your local network) require you to connect to external services from their network as they apparently enforce the use of a proxy server which intercepts HTTPS connections.

Answer (score 1):

I met the exact problem when build docker image after our company uses zscaler. The purpose is to make gem trust zscaler certificate.
First, get the zscaler certificate.
If you already have the zscaler in your mac keychain, you can run the following

```
security find-certificate -p -c "Zscaler Root CA" > ./zscaler_root_ca.pem
```

Second, copy this file to the gem folder to add certificate
e.g.

```
COPY zscaler_root_ca.pem /usr/local/lib/ruby/3.0.0/rubygems/ssl_certs/rubygems.org
```

ref doc:
https://bundler.io/guides/rubygems_tls_ssl_troubleshooting_guide.html#installing-new-rubygems-certificates

Comment: How would this be done on windows?